# how to grab output from another script

Tags: python, python-3.6

I need help with a script I am writing in python3.6.  A vendor provided us with a script that logs into their system and outputs the call records as soon as you login.  So all I get is just the raw output of all the call records constantly.  I am trying to write a script that will call the vendor script and while the vendors script is running all date will dump to a file. Once the file reaches 5mb put a timestamp on the file and rotate it.  This is what I got so far and it is not working.  The plan is to have this script run constantly.

```
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

#variables
filename = 'callLogs.txt'
dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
newName = 'callLogs'+dt+'txt'
maxFileSize = 5e6
currentFileSize = os.path.getsize(filename)

#run callLogScript
callLog = 'calllogsssh.py Calllogs abc123 172.2.3.4 > /tmp'+filename

#opens ssh session
exec(open(callLog.read())


if maxFileSize < currentFileSize: 
    os.rename(filename, newName)
    Path(filename).touch()
```

Comment: Don't use `exec` like this. There is a very rich and mature builtin api to handle use cases like this. Recommend you to take a read over the builtin `subprocess` module: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html. Think you will find support for your case spread across a few objects and methods defined in that module.

Comment: I think you have to run the script as a thread , and make the following condition as a thread's stop condition , because when you run the script , the comparaison run after the full execution of the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are some software solutions that already exist.  One package that I have used is [apache airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html) which can schedule recurring operations, that can read/write to files, as well as have downstream dependencies that wait for previous tasks to complete.